# Call MVC Controller Action in right click of mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I want to call the Controller action on right click of the mouse event.
Basically I want to call action method on a product image by right clicking on mouse and the product detail page will open in a new tab.
Please Help me how I will be able to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Jquery's `event.which` normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode` so you don't have to worry about browser compatibility issues. Documentation on event.which

event.which will give 1, 2 or 3 for left, middle and right mouse buttons respectively so:

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            console.log('Left Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('call your controller');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it has worked